# How to change the color of the dropdown menu button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

When I click the button on the dropdown menu, I want to change the color from black to transparent.

[image]

How do I change when I click on the button? I don't want the dropdown menu color to be black, rather transparent since the color looks weird on my background image. Here is the coding for the dropdown menu:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Candidates<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Name 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Name 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap css code to your button or it has class already. So you wrap to css for that class Shown in bellow likely

```
.dropdown-toggle{
     background-color: transparent ;
}
```

or else you have to replace `.navbar-inverse` to `navbar-default` on your element

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  your code here
</nav>
```

Comment: transparency ??